# Umbraco 7 Back Office fails to load in IE on IIS

Tags: iis, umbraco7

I'm developing an Umbraco 7 site, and have installed the NuGet package in Visual Studio. When I run it locally under IIS Express, everything is fine. When I deploy this to a server under IIS, I get the site pages fine but do not get the back office when I try to do any administration. All I get is a blank page.

I've not made any changes to the back office, and the site configuration on the server is the same as locally.

The user running the app pool has full control permissions on the folder.

When I navigate to the site in Firefox, I can view the back office pages, log in and do anything. In IE 11, the back office pages are blank.

What might I be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/json-is-undefined-with-jquery-min-2-0-3-on-ie-11

I managed to debug the JavaScript loading the page, and jQuery was throwing an error. It's a known issue apparently, and adding a special `<meta>` tag to the page (see link for details) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would clear cookies, restart IIS Express and hope it's fixed...

Comment: IIS Express works, it's when I try to access the site hosted in IIS that is the problem. I've restarted many, many times (server, IIS, and the site itself).

Comment: Removed cookies, still nothing.

Comment: What does the HTML of the "blank" pages gives?  Maybe try the umbraco forum at http://our.umbraco.org.forum

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a case that, when I enabled the IIS in the control panel, I forgot to enable "Static Content" feature. As soon as I enabled this feature, everything started working properly. Also make sure that the appropriate permissions are granted to users:

IUSR - for static content

IIS_IUSRS - for ASP.NET